# If $uA=0, u\geq0, u1=1$ has not solution then $Ax<0$ yes has solution.

Tags: inequality, optimization, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Prove that given a matrix $m \times n$, the system $A x < 0$ has
solution if and only if $u A = 0, u \geqslant 0, u 1 = 1$ has not solution.

My attempt:
I was able to prove the necessary condition but I have problems with the sufficiency.

Assuming that exists $x$ such that $A x < 0$, we suppose that exists $u$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
    u A & = & 0 \nonumber\\
    u & \geqslant & 0  \tag{1}\\
    u 1 & = & 1. \nonumber
  \end{eqnarray}
For the last condition, $u$ can't be zero. Then exists at least a coordenate $u_i$ of $u$ that is positive. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
    u (A x) & < & u. 0\\
    (u A) x & < & 0\\
    0 x & < & 0\\
    0 & < & 0,
  \end{eqnarray*}
which is a contradiction, therefore the system 1 has not solution.

For the reverse I don't know how to begin. I only know if I take $u=(1,0,...,0)$ then $[A_{1j}]$ must has someone cordenate diferent to zero, and thus for the others rows of $A$.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: What you want to show is known as "Farkas Lemma". I'm sure you can find some proofs online. As far as I remember you are showing that either one of these systems has a solution and not directly the $\Rightarrow$ and the $\Leftarrow$ direction

Comment: @LegNaiB I justo post my solution, please can you read it and tell me if I'am rigth.

Comment: Above is the demostration of $(\Rightarrow)$, and below is the demostration for $(\Leftarrow)$.

Answer (score 1):

For the reverse, we proced for contradiction. Let's suppose $Ax<0$ has not solution. So we take any vector $b<0$, then $$Ax\leq b$$ has not solution too. Then, for Farkas' lemma, the system $$uA=0,ub<0,u\geq0$$ has solution, i.e., exists $u$ such that satisfies the last system. Note $u$ has to be different to zero. We make $$u'=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^mu_i}u,$$ then $u'$ satisfies $$u'A=0,u'\geq0,u'1=1,$$ which is a contradiction with hypothesis.